# Load Numpy Array Binary Image with OpenCV detectMultiScale

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have sequences of digits originally from Mnist data set that I've manipulated with OpenCV. They are saved in a pickle file. They are 1 channel images with shape (112, 112).

I want to run these through an OpenCV Cascade Classifier, similar to [the face detection tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html), but instead with these [Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization cascades](https://github.com/ankitdhall/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization).

Here is my attempt:

```
data = p.load_file('data/train_sequences00.pickle')
zero = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade0/cascade.xml')
one = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade1/cascade.xml')
two = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade2/cascade.xml')
three = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade3/cascade.xml')
four = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade4/cascade.xml')
five = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade5/cascade.xml')
six = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade6/cascade.xml')
seven = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade7/cascade.xml')
eight = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade8/cascade.xml')
nine = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade9/cascade.xml')
gray = np.array(data['sequences'][0]).astype(np.float32)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.CV_RGB2GRAY)

zeros = zero.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
ones = one.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
twos = two.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
threes = three.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
fours = four.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
fives = five.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
sixes = size.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
sevens = seven.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
eights = eight.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
nines = nine.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
```

Unfortunately this just results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "digit_cascade.py", line 22, in <module>
    zeros = zero.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, scaleFactor=0.6)
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

Is anyone familiar with how to load raw numpy arrays into OpenCV `detectMultiscale`?

Here are some uncertainties I have:

- The [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) have two different signatures for `detectMultiscale`. What is the purpose of the first, with the arguments for `rejectLevels` and `levelWeights`?
- My images are 112x112. Each digit within this image would be around 11x11 pixels. The cascade sizes are 20x30. What parameter should I/ do I need to set in order for the cascades to work properly?

System info:

```
cv2.__version__ # '2.4.11'
sys.version #'2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)]'
```

Comment: That's a rather odd error message, I'd expect to get some meaningful exception (or assert) message. What version of OpenCV is that? What Python? What platform? Did the XML load properly? (What's the result of `zeros.empty()`?)

Comment: @DanMašek Updated with the versions. It seems the cascades loaded properly. `zero.empty() # False`.

Answer (score 1):

I can run the classifier using same cascade files while loading data directly from image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

workspace = '/path/to/directory'

# cascades
cascades = [
    (cv2.CascadeClassifier(workspace + '/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade1/cascade.xml'), (255, 0, 0)),
    (cv2.CascadeClassifier(workspace + '/Google-Street-View-House-Numbers-Digit-Localization/cascades/cascade6/cascade.xml'), (0, 255, 0))
]

# input
img = cv2.imread('/path/to/image/house-number-16.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# detect and mark
for cascade, color in cascades:
    digits = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in digits:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

# show result
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The result (it fails to detect "1" though):

[image: the result]

I suspect your problem lies in the way you save images from pickle or the way you load them.

For instance, by default `cv2.imread` read image to integer `numpy.ndarray`. When I change it to float (eg. dividing by 255), I get an error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scaleFactor > 1 && image.depth() ==
>   CV_8U) in detectMultiScale, file
>   /home/yohanesgultom/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp,
>   line 1081 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cascade.py", line
>   21, in 
>       digits = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) cv2.error: /home/yohanesgultom/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1081:
>   error: (-215) scaleFactor > 1 && image.depth() == CV_8U in function
>   detectMultiScale

I run it on Ubuntu:

```
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.13'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) \n[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]'
```

Comment: Right, as I stated in the post, I am loading these images in binary format ie as numpy arrays. I feel dumb for not realizing this last night, but because my binary images were already single channel (ie gray scale) there's no need to call `cvtColor`. Simply `gray = np.array(data['sequences'][0]).astype(np.uint8)` and feed to cascades as `one.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)` and it works. Leaving this here in case anyone else wants more clarification: http://answers.opencv.org/question/131606/load-single-channel-numpy-array-image-with-detectmultiscale/?answer=131615#post-id-131615 Thanks.